# create thumbnails of images and videos uploaded to s3?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

I need to create thumbnails of images and videos uploaded to s3. My current plan is to use sns to send a message and add to an SQS when media is uploaded. And then just pop off media from SQS and do the processing and upload to s3 from a node js app.

Is there a more elegant way to do this? I'd like to not use the bandwidth of downloading each image/video and then uploading 2 thumbnails each. Is there a more cloud friendly way to do this with aws?

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally try to avoid running and maintaining infrastructure (EC2 instances, SQS queues, SNS topics etc.) for this, if possible.

You could easily use Lambda for the [image to thumbnails](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/walkthrough-s3-events-adminuser.html) step, and perhaps look at Elastic Transcoder for video to thumbnails though I'm not sure if it can create just thumbnails without also doing video transcoding.

Also see:

- [Can I use Amazon Elastic Transcoder to only create thumbnails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604916/can-i-use-amazon-elastic-transcoder-to-only-create-thumbnails)
- [Elegant way to create thumbnails of images stored on s3 with ec2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013999/elegant-way-to-create-thumbnails-of-images-stored-on-s3-with-ec2-and-communicate)